# tunneling ssh through ssh

Tags: networking, server, ssh, tunnel

I access a Beowulf cluster which only allows local connections when I am at work. To work on the cluster from home, I login to an onsite ssh server then run a simple ssh script, to login to the cluster.
What i want to do is have 1 script I can run at home to link my up to the on site ssh server, then onto the cluster. 
My ssh sever that accesses the cluster is Ubuntu 13.04, and my home client computer is Ubuntu 12.04

how can i tell ssh to execute a script once it logs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` allows by default executing commands, e.g.

```
ssh <host> <command>
```

or

```
ssh <host> '<command1>; <command2>'
```

In your case, you will probably need to specify `-t` to force tty allocation on the middle-server. So try something like:

```
ssh -t <your gateway> '<script call>'
```